# Is there a python construct that is a dummy function?

Tags: python, function, nonetype

Is there a python construct that corresponds to a function taking no argument, doing nothing and returning nothing ? Something similar to object `None` but that would be a function instead of an object ?

### The context

I want to define a class where the constructor gets a function as an argument and references it to a class attribute. Upon instanciation, the user decides whether he/she wants that function to be an actual function which he/she defines him/herself or leave the default which is to call a dummy function which does nothing.

Here is what I have now :

```
def sayHello():
    print("hello world !")

def doNothing():
    pass

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, myFunc):
        self.doIt = myFunc

myInstance = myClass(sayHello)
myInstance.doIt()
myInstance = myClass(doNothing) # Works but requires defining function doNothing()
myInstance.doIt()
#myInstance = myClass(None) # Returns error "'NoneType' object is not callable"
myInstance.doIt()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about lambdas?

```
myInstance = myClass(lambda:None)
```

Sure you can pass is as default to your `__init__` function:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, myFunc = lambda:None):
        self.doIt = myFunc
```

Comment: I think function objects are mutable which makes me believe this is a tricky idea. I wouldn't make it the default argument like that (instead use a function object that is re-created) unless I'm sure no one can access and change it...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, myFunc = lambda : None):
        self.doIt = myFunc

myInstance = myClass()
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following:

```
a=lambda:None
a()
print a()
```

The latter line prints None.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`def none(function=True):
     if function==True:
         return None
     else:
         function()`